# How to connect containers on same network on Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, scrapy, docker-compose

I'm having a difficult time trying to connect our scrapy scheduler, spiderkeeper, to scrapyd on my local Mac environment.

Both services are in different containers on the same network.

Spiderkeeper uses the `SERVERS` variable to connect to our `scrapyd` servers, but I get a connection refused.

When SSHing into spiderkeeper and running `curl -v scrapyd:6800`, the containers refuse to connect.

What's really weird is when I SSH in to the `scrapyd` container and run `curl -v spiderkeeper:5000` I get a response, and when we deploy the same exact setup to kubernetes, the containers communicate fine, but for local purposes, this is a nightmare.

Here is `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  scrapyd:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "6800:6800"
    depends_on:
      - spiderkeeper

  spiderkeeper:
    image: <our_spiderkeeper_image>
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      SERVERS: "scrapyd:6800"
```

What am I missing locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for communicating between containers are putting the containers on the same docker network, your application listens on all interfaces, and the client uses the container name or service alias and container port to communicate (not the host published port).

For the shared network, the docker compose yaml v2 and newer give you this by default (you only need to manually define networks to override this behavior). There's nothing to do here.

For the client connection, you are attempting to communicate with the service alias and the container port, so that part is also correct.

---

We cannot see that the application is correctly listening on all interfaces. My preferred way to troubleshoot that involves running a debugging container:

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:${container_id} nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt
```

The `${container_id}` above is your scrapyd container id or name. You should see a line with either:

```
0.0.0.0:6800
:::6800
```

If instead you see a line with either:

```
127.0.0.1:6800
::1:6800
```

Then your application is listening on the loopback interface which is not supported. You need to reconfigure that to `0.0.0.0` in your application configuration.

And if you see none of these, then your application is not listening on the network at all and it's time to start debugging the app, digging into the logs, etc.

---

One last thing to adjust is to remove the dependency between services in your docker-compose file. This dependency will not solve all issues you want it to solve, and it will not work at all if you migrate to swarm mode. Instead, the best practice is to configure your client application to poll for the remote service to become available and gracefully fail if that does not happen within an appropriate timeout. It's very easy to have a race condition where docker starts your second service before the first service has finished starting and is listening on the port, resulting in a connection refused. (I doubt this is the issue since you described logging in manually, presumably after the application would have had enough time to start.)

See also this [note in the docker documentation on depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) for why I recommend against it:

> **There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:**
>
> - depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait
>     for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on
>     this problem and strategies for solving it.
> - Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.
> - The depends_on option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.

Comment: Winner winner! Thanks for the assist @BMitch - the app wasnt listening on all ports. Now it is. Now it's working. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly, i had to do the following for this behavior.

1. Create a locally bridged docker network

`docker network create my_local_net --subnet 192.168.130.0/24 --attachable --gateway 192.168.130.1`

2. Add to your docker-compose file, at the end.

   `networks:
     default:
       external:
        name: my_local_net`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this before and it still doesn't work. Confirmed that both services are on the network with `docker network inspect my_local_net` but still get the the connection refused

Comment: Couple questions:  Have you interactively gotten a bash prompt to both machines to verify you have an IP on each, and they are in the same subnet?  Can the machine ping each other by IP?  Is it only resolution   failing?  Also, what is the host OS and which version of Docker are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  scrapyd:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "6800:6800"
    depends_on:
      - spiderkeeper

    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - scrapyd
    hostname: scrapyd

  spiderkeeper:
    image: <our_spiderkeeper_image>
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      SERVERS: "scrapyd:6800"
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - spiderkeeper
    hostname: spiderkeeper

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, but still getting the same refused connection errors

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `localhost:6800` instead of `scrapyd:6800`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. The containers are communicating between each other on their own network. I'm not trying to communicate from my machine to the container.